# Is traveling inherently sleep inducing?

Tags: sleeping

I always find it curious how no matter: the time of day, the mode of transportation, the duration of the journey - traveling seems to be incredibly sleep inducing.

By traveling I mean - taking transportation - actual moving and going around, would more likely be stimulating rather than sleep inducing.

Is there any support to back up this thinking?

Comment: Not from me. I enjoy travel. I find it exciting.

Comment: I appreciate you may be asking for sources instead of opinions, though the question would benefit if you can define 'travelling' in this context. Is it leisure travel, business travel, commute, or just moving from point A to point B etc.?

Comment: @B.Liu I added a sentence saying: *[b]y traveling I mean - taking transportation [....]*, is that helpful?

Comment: Tangentially, you might want to run yourself through the [Epworth sleepiness scale](https://www.blf.org.uk/support-for-you/obstructive-sleep-apnoea-osa/diagnosis/epworth-sleepiness-scale) test

Comment: Not for me. Can't sleep on transport even if up for 48 hours and exhausted.